# Operator AND is not function property

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a procedure in SQL Server like this:

```
select 
  column1, 
  column2... 
from 
  table 
where 
  column1 = abc 
  and column2 = 245  
  and condition3 
  and condition4
```

But the `SELECT` is selecting values that failed condition, I need restrict the selection. For example:

```
column1 column2
 abc    123
 cdf    245
 ghi    678
```

Comment: We really need the conditions you are actually using instead of *something like this*. It is very very very likely that you have an error on your conditions and not that `AND` is not working properly

Comment: @Lamak yes. it seems like this is more likely an issue with order of operations

Comment: You need to clarify this with some actual data if possible.

Comment: I'd agree with @Lamak, except I'd phrase it a bit stronger... .  not "very very very likely", but ...  "absolutely certainly"

Comment: SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 From Table Where Column1 = 'abc' and Column2 = 123 and Column3 = '456' The output inclue values that failed condition...

Comment: @user1991662 This is almost certainly an anomaly in your data or your query.  Can you show ACTUAL data and an ACTUAL query in your question to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @user1991662 What are you getting? I'm confused and have a head cold so I can't really decipher. Give us the schema, the data, all the conditions, and what you want the result set to look like.

Comment: I getting some columns of the one Table with four AND condition for restriction but the AND condiction is failed... Is showing data that are out of the conditions....

Comment: @user1991662 Do you have any `OR` in your filters?

Comment: Sanitizing the table and column names is all well and good, but if there was something wrong with AND in SQL Server 2008, five years later, the community would know by now.  Feel free to change column and table names, but the actual text of the query is really important to solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this despite there being incomplete information in your post.

A chain of just `AND` operators will require every expression to evaluate true for every row returned. This is as fundamental as gravity.

In short, `AND` works, it just doesn't work as you expect it to.

What is likely going on here is you have other expressions in your query that you don't feel are relevant to the question.

For example

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3
FROM myTable
WHERE Column1 = 'abc'
   AND Column2 = 123
   AND column3 = 'zyx'
   OR Column3 = 'xyz'
```

Is logically completely different from:

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3
FROM myTable
WHERE Column1 = 'abc'
   AND Column2 = 123
   AND (column3 = 'zyx'
   OR Column3 = 'xyz')
```

In the first example the generally accepted order of operations would evaluate your query as

```
 (Column1 = 'ABC AND Column2 = 123 AND column3 = 'zyx')
```

Meaning all of the above must be true

```
 OR Column3 = 'xyz'
```

In case 1, any row with column3 equal to 'xyz' will be returned regardless of whether the `AND` operations evaluate as true. You're saying give me a row if EITHER the and operations or the OR operation are true.

If you want SQL to evaluate your expression differently, you need to specify priority using parenthesis as in case 2.

For more information, take a look at [msdn operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) you'll see that ANDs are evaluated long before ORs.

Also, if you post your *actual* query we can be more specific in our help as to where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your syntax is incorrect, causing the "AND"s to be applied to one side of the predicate of each predicate - for example ('123' AND column2) will return true unless column2 is 0(false) or Null. You can try wrapping your predicates in parentheses - at least that might cause SQL Server to throw an error pointing you in the right direction.